# asignar variable a un select

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

quiero ejecutar una funcion pasando como variable el nombre del select
por ejemplo, en esta función, necesitaría pasar $combobox1...$combobox2...$combobox3 etc...

Es posible.., o tengo que utilizar una función para cada Combobox....
Donde puedo encontrar información para este problema en concreto.....

```
function borra(valor){

 $('#Combobox1 option:selected').remove();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tendría que ser:

```
function borra(valor){
 $('#'+valor+' option:selected').remove();
}
```

Lo único que hay que tener cuidado es con las comillas.

Por cierto, con este código estás seleccionando el elemento por id, si lo que necesitas es seleccionarlo por nombre, tendría que ser:

```
function borra(nombreElemento){
 $('select[name="'+nombreElemento+'"] option:selected').remove();
}
```

Tienes toda la información en la documentación de jquery: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Y los selectores CSS3 en: https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/